# Images not showing up when previewing from file

Tags: html, css, macos

Hi I'm a novice programmer and I'm working on making my first website. I'm working on a Mac and whenever I go to preview the file directly from finder my CSS and Images don't show up even though the paths are correct. When I preview the files in Dreamweaver CS6 and Brackets the sight looks exactly how I want it but not when I choose to preview directly from the file. Here are the CSS and HTML files. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.Here is a screenshot of what happens[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIqMm.png)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#menuBar{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: -10px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#logo {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    right:1100px;
}

#menuButton, #aboutButton, #locationButton, #cateringButton{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    color: white;
    font-family:Futura;
    font-size:10px;
    top:30px;
}

#menuButton {
    right:610px;
}

#aboutButton {
    right:475px;
}

#locationButton{
    right:308px;
}

#cateringButton{
    right:150px;
}

#facebookButton{
    right:60px;
    top:40px;
    position: fixed;
    height:40px;
    width: 50px;
    z-index:5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<link href="Roundhouse/CSS/homePage.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="menuBar"><img src="Roundhouse/Images/MenuBar.png" alt="menu Bar" width="100%" height="125px" />
    </div>
<div id="logo">
<img src="Roundhouse/Images/Round-House.gif" alt="logo" width="100px" height="100px" /></div>

<div id="menuButton">
    <h1>MENU</h1>
    </div>
<div id="aboutButton">
    <h1>ABOUT</h1>
    </div>
<div id="locationButton">
    <h1>LOCATION</h1>
    </div>
<div id="cateringButton">
    <h1>CATERING</h1>
    </div>
<div id="facebookButton">

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/RoundhouseBBQ/?rf=205148012847894" target="_blank"> <img src="Roundhouse/Images/facebooklogo.png" border="0" alt="facebook" height="30px" width="30px" >
</a>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you screenshot what is the result?

Comment: I added it to the description

Comment: check the developer tools, and check if your path are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the path is correct if the folder `RoundHouse` is next to your html file.

If that doesnt work, try using the absolute path and try to inclue `file://` . A better way is to bring up a local http server and place your html and image files there.

Answer (score 0):

I am understaing that your site folder structure is as follow:

```
/Roundhouse{root-folder}
    /Images
    /CSS
    index.html
```

If index.html or whatever root HTML file is located as I assumed it will be, then you should remove the extra "Roundhouse/" subpath from all of your paths. Because from inside of your targeted HTML file (index.html) you should start accessing files relatively to its location.

So for instance, according to the above structure, if you have back.png image inside of Images folder, you can display it as follow:

```
<img src="Images/back.png">
```

Hope this will help. Try to read more about HTML/CSS file traversing:

http://www.itechflare.com/main/html-css-file-path-quick-tips/

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your response I am just confused as to why it works in the Dreamweaver and Brackets preview but not when previewing directly from the file. Any ideas?

Comment: I am a big fan of Notepad++, so really don't know. However, my best guess is that Dreamweaver as an IDE might have extra metadata that allow it to figure out miss-typed paths intelligently.